# HTML5 images not aligning correctly with same css

Tags: css, html, image, web

I am trying to align two images in two divs. These are the two images, they are the same size, resolution, and the aligning is perfect when doing it in photoshop:
[image]

But when I reference them in my index.html like so:

```
<!-- Intro Header -->
<div class="intro">
    <div class="intro-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h2>ssss</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-------acerca---------->

<div id="acerca" class="acerca">
    <div class="acerca-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h2>Acerca de Cssss</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the exact same css classes:

```
.intro {
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 100px 0;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/jDhQ6PP.jpg?1) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
background-color: #000;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
}

.intro .intro-body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.intro .intro-body .brand-heading {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.intro .intro-body .intro-text {
    font-size: 18px;
}


.acerca {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 100px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
     background: url(http://i.imgur.com/raMFNcc.png?1) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

.acerca .acerca-body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.acerca .acerca-body .brand-heading {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.acerca .acerca-body .acerca-text {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

And the images do not align as you can see in this picture:
[image]

I can't post images because of lacking reputation points, this is only my second question.

Do anyone know how to align them? Thanks.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uyo35tuf/

Comment: Put this on jsfiddle and provide a link so we can help :)

Comment: Can you post the correct image URLs in CSS? It will help us examine better.

Comment: @LloanAlas https://jsfiddle.net/uyo35tuf/

Comment: Have you tried using `background-position: center;`?

Comment: @PavSidhu yes, not aligning them either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look like you want use

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Cover it is not the same

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

> **cover** This keyword specifies that the background image should be
>   scaled to be as small as possible while ensuring both its dimensions
>   are greater than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the
>   background positioning area.

I found a very useful explanation about:
http://blog.vjeux.com/2013/image/css-container-and-cover.html

And you don´t need prefix
http://shouldiprefix.com/#background-image-options

As well I propose to you a solution:

CSS

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
body{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.intro, .acerca{
    flex:1;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff; 

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.intro {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/jDhQ6PP.jpg?1) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.acerca {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/raMFNcc.png?1) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="intro">
        <h1>ssss</h1>
</div>

<div id="acerca" class="acerca">
       <h2>Acerca de Cssss</h2>
</div>
```

You have a example here with the proper prefixs. http://jsfiddle.net/luarmr/y33yc91z/2/

Comment: Thank you that resolves the problem when full window mode, but when resizing the screen this happens: http://i.imgur.com/4EGTr0m.png?1  @Raúl Martín

Comment: @MarianaHernandez Also checkout my answer, you need to use viewport height instead of auto in order to prevent that resizing issue.

Comment: In you case i propose to you use only one picture, or only fix horizontally. In this design look posible use only a single picture.

Comment: Better to use a single picture.

Comment: @MarianaHernandez If you are happy with the answer, you remember to mark it as a valid.

Comment: As well I still think about and don´t make sense the image that you sent to me. I think, the problem is a some paddings that you have in the page, I simplified the css and the html and create a example with flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Raul's suggestion, I played around the code and got the output as needed. `100% 100%` will make the image render as it is and responsive as well.

Also replace `height: auto` with `height: 50vh`. It tells the browser to occupy 50% of the view port height. Thus it makes 100vh for the two divs.

```css
.intro {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/jDhQ6PP.jpg?1) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.intro .intro-body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.intro .intro-body .brand-heading {
  font-size: 40px;
}
.intro .intro-body .intro-text {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.acerca {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/raMFNcc.png?1) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.acerca .acerca-body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.acerca .acerca-body .brand-heading {
  font-size: 40px;
}
.acerca .acerca-body .acerca-text {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Intro Header -->
<div class="intro">
  <div class="intro-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
          <h2>ssss</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-------acerca---------->

<div id="acerca" class="acerca">
    <div class="acerca-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h2>Acerca de Cssss</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It gets better but it is still resizing differently http://i.imgur.com/ICqCzq4.png?1

Comment: Did you set 50vh for both the divs?

Comment: It works perfectly here. Maybe any other code that is interfering?

Comment: when pasting your code works great but when i try to add element inside the <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"> divs  i get the same problem. I added an <a> and some images

Comment: Create the JSfiddle of the new code please. Go with a single image instead.

Comment: There will be complications. Go with a single image.